# How to select a column based on date condition in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

My query is I want to select list of users whose date of birth is system date, I have used the following condition in my controller, but it is giving an error.
I want to omit year, and select users whose date of birth is same as system's date and month.

**Error:**

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

**Controller Code:**

```
objUser.UserBirthdays = dbContext.EmployeeProfiles.Where(u => Convert.ToDateTime(u.DOB).ToString("dd-MMM").Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM"))).Select(u => u.Name).ToList();
```

UserBirthdays is defined in the **model** as :

```
public IEnumerable<string> UserBirthdays { get; set; }
```

How to resolve this error, and get usernames?

Comment: `var dob = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM"); objUser.UserBirthdays = dbContext.EmployeeProfiles.Where(u => u.DOB == dob).Select(u => u.Name).ToList();` (but that will depend of what DOB is in your db)

Comment: What is the format of `DOB` in the database, and why is it a string instead of a DateTime? (I'm assuming its a `string` because otherwise, why would you use `Convert.ToDateTime()`)

Comment: Datatype of DOB is datetime in database.

Comment: Then `Convert.ToDateTime()` is pointless. Are you wanting to match all records where the day and month of `DOB` match today's day and month (but can be any year)

Comment: Yes. You got my point. If User A and B have DOB is  29-Aug-1990 & 29-Aug-1987 it should give result A and B, matching only the date and month part.

Comment: You can use `.Where(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", x) == month && SqlFunctions.DatePart("d", x) == day)` (but declare `month` and `day` first - e.g. `int month = DateTime.Today.Month;`

Comment: This doesnt work. Can you please make changes to the above LINQ query ?

Answer (score 2):

This will get all the users with DOB today:

If DOB is of `DateTime` Type:

```
objUser.UserBirthdays = dbContext.EmployeeProfiles
                          .Where(u => u.DOB.Day == DateTime.Today.Day 
                                   && u.DOB.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
                          .Select(u => u.Name).ToList();
```

If the `DOB` data type is Nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`), then you need to check for nulls first and convert the DOB to `DateTime`:

```
objUser.UserBirthdays = dbContext.EmployeeProfiles
                          .Where(u => u.DOB != null 
                                    && Convert.ToDateTime(u.DOB).Day == DateTime.Today.Day
                                    && Convert.ToDateTime(u.DOB).Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
                          .Select(u => u.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Removing the `ToList()`  will defer the execution of the query (not necessarily a bad thing, just a note)

Comment: @yinnonsanders added it back

Comment: This is not working. Please suggest how to populate a list of name matching the date and month..

Comment: @SameepBaxi what is the type of `DOB`? is it `DateTime` or `DateTime? (nullable datetime)`

Comment: I used the above methodology as you described. But it is getting cartesian result of all the usernames where DOB contains records of 8th Month (current month) and DOB that has date 29th (current system date).
Its like all the users which have DOB as August, but different dates are coming, and all the users with DOB as 29th (current), but different months are coming as a result.

Comment: @SameepBaxi how? The `&&` condition will take care of that. Get all the DOB with `Day` same as today **and** `Month` same today

Comment: Thanks @adiga. It worked. Earlier I was using Datetime.Now instead of DateTime.Today. Thanks!!

Comment: @SameepBaxi well `DateTime.Now` should also work. Also please accept the answer.

Comment: I need to work here with nullable type. Your code here for nullable type isn't working. In my Model it's like: 
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
Error: Nullable<System.DateTime> doesn't contain definition for 'Day'. Please help.

Comment: `Nullable<System.DateTime>` and `DateTime?` are the same thing. So, the second block with `Convert.ToDateTime(u.DOB)` should work.